# Inner join with select on HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to do something like that with HQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN (select fieldA, sum(fieldB) as sum from tableB) b
ON a.fieldA = b.fieldA and a.fieldC = b.sum;
```

But this gives an error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: (...
```

There is any way to make this using HQL and Hibernate?

Comment: No, HQL doesn't allow inner selects in that position. There may be a way for you to rephrase that, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try the **native SQL** solution approach:

need toimport this first:

```
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
```

then somewhere in your code:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM tableA a
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT fieldA, sum(fieldB) as sum from tableB) b
    ON a.fieldA = b.fieldA and a.fieldC = b.sum"
);
```

**[more on this link](http://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/hibernate)** 
**[and HERE (
Joins in Hibernate Query Language)](http://levelup.lishman.com/hibernate/hql/joins.php)**

Comment: Yeah, native can be a solution, but I would love a HQL solution, there isn't any? :(

Comment: Just tried the solution with the SQL, and what I didn't know is that you can set the result to an entity using `query.addEntity(TableA.class)`, or else the result would be an array of Objects. So this way works perfect to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can try to do such thing with HQL:

```
String sqlText = 
        "select entityA 
         from EntityA entityA, EntityB entityB 
         where entityA.fieldA=entityB.fieldA 
         and entityA.fieldC=(select sum(entityB.fieldB) 
                             from EntityB entityB 
                             where entityB.fieldA=entityA.fieldA)"

Query query = session.createQuery(sqlText);
```

It should work similar to your sql. About your statement - as I know you cannot use inner view in HQL because it is object oriented.

Here is a good [article](http://levelup.lishman.com/hibernate/hql/joins.php) about joins in HQL.

**EDIT:**

According to notes from user1495181 above query can be rewritten like (but I'm not sure):

```
String sqlText = 
        "select entityA 
         from EntityA entityA
         join entityA.entitiesB entityB
         Where entityA.fieldC=(select sum(entityB.fieldB) 
                             from EntityB entityB 
                             where entityB.fieldA=entityA.fieldA)"
```

But I prefer first variant because as for me it is more understandable (especially for peoples who used to work with native SQL).

Comment: If you have relation between A And B you can use join to join them and put just the condition in the where.

Comment: @user1495181 Thank you for editing). I missed to change and on where.

Comment: I like the way you rewrite the hql, but I'm not sure if it would work to my case (that is more complex than my example query :P). Using native SQL is better to me, in this case ;)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define the join with on keyword. Hibernate know how to do the join based on your mapping. 
If you define a relation in the mapping between a and b than hibernate will do the join based on the relation that you defined.
If you have relation between a and b than do inner join without using on and put the join criteria in the where clause

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Suppose that you have Manager(1:m)Employe.
The relation between them is defined in the hibernate mapping (one-to-many), so when you want to query for manager that their employee has a salary bigger that 100 than you dont need to specify the relation in the query like you do in SQL query with the join ...on.
With hibernate you query 'from manager m join m.employee e where e. salary > 100 (i didnt specify how to do the join . hibernate know it by the mapping).
However if your join is not defined in the mapping (not good practice) than you can do explicit join in the where: