# HQL : inner join

Tags: mysql, spring, hql

I want to do an inner join in my hql query but i've got this error :

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( ...

```
SELECT new myDto(
                col1, col2
            FROM table1,table2
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT foo, bar, ...  max(nb) as numberBar
                FROM table1
                GROUP BY foo, bar ...
             )  myAlias

             ON table1.foo = myAlias.foo
             AND table1.bar = myAlias.bar
             ...
```

The query works in sqldeveloper

Answer (score 0):

Just checking the query you have posted, I think you have to close the parenthesis of `new myDto` after `col2`, because in that query you have posted is not closed:

```
SELECT new myDto(
                col1, col2)
            FROM table1,table2
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT foo, bar, ...  max(nb) as numberBar
                FROM table1
                GROUP BY foo, bar ...
             )  myAlias

             ON table1.foo = myAlias.foo
             AND table1.bar = myAlias.bar
             ...
```

Comment: Actually, HQL seems to not support `inner join` with `select` :/ . I'll post my workaround. thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't seem to support `inner join` with followed by `select`
[Inner join with select on HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776932/inner-join-with-select-on-hql)
I manage to make it work :

```
 SELECT new myDto(
  //usual colums selection here
  from table1, table2 
 where ...
 AND ....

// solution  here without inner join
AND (  table1.foo, table1.bar, nb)
IN (select foo, bar, max(nb) as number
    from table1     
    group by foo, bar)
```